# How to capture video quality in android youtube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I have included the YouTube API in an app , I want to know the resolution of the video at any point of time when it is running in auto mode . What methods do I need to include?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the resolution of the video by using [`fileDetails`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties), The `fileDetails` object encapsulates information about the video file that was uploaded to YouTube, including the file's resolution, duration, audio and video codecs, stream bitrates, and more. This data can only be retrieved by the video owner.

The fileDetails object will only be returned if the [processingDetails.fileAvailability](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties) property has a value of *available*.

*Note*: **Only the owner can get those properties**